# What is negative PWM (with switched ground)?

Tags: pwm, negative

I was reading documentation about flaps control unit for experimental aircraft, and I found, that indicator LEDs on device are dimming by something they called "`negative PWM (with switched ground)`".

After some research I found out, that this company sells some device (called DIM BOX), that converts positive PWM type to negative PWM type.

That part of product list:

[[image: Description from product list1]

Firstly, I was thinking that they mean that this negative PWM is simply PWM with negative voltage (so -12V instead of 12V). But in electrical parameters table, there is clearly written that OUT voltage is also positive, only current is negative: [image: Electrical parameters]

It is also consistent with arrows on installation schema:
[image: Installation schema]

So, my question are:

1. I never heard anything about "`negative PWM type (switched minus)`". What is it? I can imagine, that it is somehow "reversed" usual PWM, so in *off state*, there is 12V on output, and in *on state*, there is 0V (ground), but in this case, it is only usual PWM with reversed duty cycle, isn't it?
2. How this negative PWM can be generated (or converted from positive PWM)?

[Here is full product list pdf for this "DIM BOX" device](https://lambert-aerodevices.cz/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/dimbox_productlist_en.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably, the device converts a High-side switched PWM into a Low-side switched PWM signal.

So it pretty much converts from the right hand to the left hand in the following image:
[image: Low side vis High side switch]
[Image Source](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-high-side-low-side-driver-in-electronics)

I would assume that this device simply consists of one N-channel MOSFET, and one or two resistors. And possibly some over-voltage protection if applicable.